# SetTimeout not executing for on mousedown/touchstart function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://jsbin.com/AYeFEHi/1/edit

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? (Running Chromium on Linux)

I'm trying to only execute the alertbox when the button is down for 2s, if it's not then to clear the timeout function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing onmousedown setTimeout alert</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function call() {
  alert('Hello World!');
}

$("#alertme").on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  setTimeout(call, 2000);
});

$("#alertme").on('mouseup touchend', function() {
  clearTimeout(call, 0);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="alertme">Alert me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `clearTimeout` works.  You need to pass it the value that `setTimeout` returns.

```
function call() {
  alert('Hello World!');
}

var callTimeout = null; // hold onto the identifier for the timeout

$("#alertme").on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  callTimeout = setTimeout(call, 2000);
});

$("#alertme").on('mouseup touchend', function() {
  clearTimeout(callTimeout); // clear the timeout identifier we saved.
});
```

And you probably want to wrap this in a jQuery page ready callback so the script can be anywhere on the page:

```
$(function() {
  var call = function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
  }

  var callTimeout = null;

  $("#alertme").on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
    callTimeout = setTimeout(call, 2000);
  });

  $("#alertme").on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    clearTimeout(callTimeout);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why the script doesn't work when added above the body tags? The script only executes when embedded after the button tags.

Comment: Because script tags are parsed and executed when they are encountered. So the elements it operates on do not exist yet s the parser has not got to them yet.  Which is why jQuery provides the `$(function() { you.code.here() }` function which only fire _after_ the page is loaded.